# Update-ing dynamodb item using Appsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

In AppSync i want to update item with array or stringset like this:

```
mutation addmeta{
  addMetaDataOnPhoto(id:"xyz", metadata:["word1", "word2",...]){
    metadata
  }
}
```

this is how my mutation type looks:

```
type Mutatation{
    addMetaDataOnPhoto(id: String!, metadata: [String]!): Photo
}
```

My question is how should look resolver for this mutation.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to update an attribute without replacing the entire item, you should use the [`UpdateItem` DynamoDB operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html).

In your example, if you want to replace the `metadata` array, your request mapping template shoud look like below:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "UpdateItem",
    "key" : {
        "id" : { "S" : "${context.arguments.id}" }
    },
    "update" : {
        "expression" : "SET metadata = :vals",
        "expressionValues": {
            ":vals" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.metadata)      
        }
    }
}
```

*Note:* `$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson` will convert your array into a DynamoDB typedValue. For more information and utilities see the [AWS AppSync util reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html#dynamodb-helpers-in-util-dynamodb).

Comment: Hey thanks, but im not sure that is what i need, maybe my question wasnt formated good, im still new at this. So, i need to update one column in dynamodb table with elements that are pased through mutatuion argument in stringset format or whatever colection format. I found good example (example no.2)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-updateitem
but im still have a InvalidUpdateExpreesion syntax error near #metadata = :metadata. I cant find where is my mistake. 
Thanks

Comment: @Tinou, i have copied your code and it is just returning a null and not updating.  Is there a way to get log files or more info.

Comment: @tkerwood you can enable logging to CloudWatch on your AppSync API via the console for instance on the Settings page. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/monitoring.html